# Trying to pass data to React gives a TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, electron

My app that uses Electron with SQLite database and React on frontend. I am trying to pass the data to React but it gives me this error:

> <Await> caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send'),

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron') 

const path = require('path')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1200,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
        )

        let db = new sqlite3.Database('C:/Users/loran/Documents/GitHub/ca.ticketing.desktop/public/chinook.db', (err, success) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log('Database opening error: ', err);
          }
      });
  
      ipcMain.on('execute-sql', (event, arg) => {
          let sql = 'SELECT * FROM tracks';
  
          db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  event.reply('sql-execution-result', {
                      error: err.message,
                      rows: null
                  });
              } else {
                  console.log(rows);
                  event.reply('sql-execution-result', {
                      error: null,
                      rows: rows
                  });
              }
          });
      });
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    createWindow();
})
```

preload.js :

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = window.require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  send: (callback) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('execute-sql');
  
    ipcRenderer.once('sql-execution-result', (event, result) => { 
      if (result.error) {
        console.log('Error:', result.error);
      } else {
        callback(result.rows);
        console.log('Rows:', result.rows);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

list-tracks.jsx :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const ListTracks = () => {
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.api.send((receivedTracks) => {
      setTracks(receivedTracks);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {tracks.map((track) => (
        <div key={track.TrackId}>
          <div>TrackId: {track.TrackId}</div>
          <div>Name: {track.Name}</div>
          <div>AlbumId: {track.AlbumId}</div>
          <div>MediaTypeId: {track.MediaTypeId}</div>
          <div>GenreId: {track.GenreId}</div>
          <div>Composer: {track.Composer}</div>
          <div>Milliseconds: {track.Milliseconds}</div>
          <div>Bytes: {track.Bytes}</div>
          <div>UnitPrice: {track.UnitPrice}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I feel React does not know what is `window.api.send`. How can I pass data to React with preload.js and main.js?